# Why is ''.join() significantly slower than string concatenation here?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Problem link: [2096. Step-By-Step Directions From a Binary Tree Node to Another](https://leetcode.com/problems/step-by-step-directions-from-a-binary-tree-node-to-another/).

I was solving a problem that asks us to output the shortest step-by-step path between a start node and a destination node in a binary tree, where traveling to left and right children are denoted by ‘L’ and ‘R’, and traveling to a parent node is denoted by ‘U’. We are given the reference to the root node, and the number of nodes n can be as large as 100,000.

My solution is as follows:

- Run a BFS to find both start and destination nodes, while generating the paths along the way using arrays. Once we find both nodes, return the path arrays.
- Now that we have paths to both start and destination nodes, find the lowest common ancestor of the two nodes by throwing out any initial common letters (e.g. if startPath = [‘L’, ‘R’, ‘L’] and destPath = [‘L’, ‘L’, ‘R’], the lowest common ancestor is root.left, and the remaining startPath from this lowest common ancestor is [‘R’, ‘L’].)
- Finally, to get the path between startNode and destNode, we can convert all remaining startPath letters to ‘U’s, and then add on the remaining destPath.

The relevant code pertaining to the question is as follows:

```
def bfs_path2(root, target1, target2):
    q = deque([(root, [])])
    while q and not (found1 and found2):
        node, path = q.popleft()
        if node.left:
            q.append((node.left, path + ['L']))
        if node.right:
            q.append((node.right, path + ['R']))
    return path1, path2

s_path, t_path = bfs_path2(root, startValue, destValue)
# i, j legal indices of s_path and t_path
return "".join(['U']*len(s_path[i:]) + t_path[j:])
```

The runtime of this against a large test case was >10s. However, if I change the implementation of the BFS queue elements to strings, it runs in ~3s:

```
def bfs_path2(root, target1, target2):
    q = deque([(root, '')])
    while q and not (found1 and found2):
        node, path = q.popleft()
        if node.left:
            q.append((node.left, path + 'L'))
        if node.right:
            q.append((node.right, path + 'R'))
    return path1, path2

s_path, t_path = bfs_path2(root, startValue, destValue)
# i, j legal indices of s_path and t_path
return 'U'*len(s_path[i:]) + t_path[j:]
```

There are many links on StackOverflow showing that string concatenation is far slower than the join() method in Python, so I’m confused as to why the first code runtime is much slower than the second code runtime. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Almost none of the code relevant to the question.. note that there is also no "join vs concat" going on here. Instead, the relevant signatures are `(str * int) + str` vs `string.join(list_of_one_item * int) + str`.

Comment: Because it's a *single* concatenation. Also, `['U']*len(s_path[i:]) ` creates a list, and *then* joins it, which is much less efficient than `'U'*len(s_path[i:])` (which is about the fastest way to create that string in Python).

Comment: Yes, please remove all the irrelevant code and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please create a minimal code example for your issue and give it exact benchmark results.

Comment: Ah, it’s just a single concatenation - got it. And (array + [‘L’]) is probably just as bad as (str + ‘L’). If that’s the case, then the biggest difference between the two versions would be the single join? Does that sound reasonable for a ~7s difference?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's even better to do `"U"*(len(s_path)-i)` to avoid to create a slice of `s` just to compute it's length

Comment: @azi I *suspect* the majority of the time difference is with `['U'] * very_large_integer`, and not the actual `join(..)` call itself. If curious, write some benchmarks to profile `['U'] * i`, `join(['U'] * i)`, and `'U' * i`. Then plot the graph for different values of `i` ranging from "very small" to "very large".

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks everyone! :)